# How to Change Contents of a Div Depending on Document Width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I have simplified my code:

Basically, I'm just wondering how to change the arrangement of these divs:

```
<div id='ele1'></div>

<div id='ele_container'>
   <div id='ele2'></div>
   <div id='ele3'></div>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div id='ele1'>
   <div id='ele2'></div>
   <div id='ele3'></div>
</div>

<div id='ele_container'></div>
```

Depending on screen resolution. So if the screen resolution is less than 800px- the first, and greater than- the second arrangement.

I know I can use document.width() and an if/else statement using jquery's .html, but this will not account for if the user resizes the window.

Regards,
Taylor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you said is correct, use the width and an if/else.  To handle resizing just use the resize event:

http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Answer (score 0):

You can always detect resize, like this

```
window.onresize = function(){ /* stuff */ };
```

What are you trying to achieve (visually) are you sure it is not possible with plain css?

Comment: It would be possible but I would have to duplicate the contents of the containers instead of just moving it using jQuery. This would be OK but the content is dynamically loaded